# Moving from data preprocessing to a model and hyper parameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I am new to machine learning and I am having trouble with fitting a data set for a classification model. What I would like to know is after pre processing data and fitting to a model with just default hyper parameters, how much performance can I expect?

To clarify,

From the basic logistic regression model that I have trained, I am getting around 50% accuracy for both test and train sets, can I expect a big jump in performance with just hyperparameter tuning?

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not.

The "may not" part :

If your cleaning, feature engineering and pre-processing steps are too shallow, you won't get a big increase in performance since you'll still be in a "garbage in, garbage out" step.
You might also not have enough data, and your model is underfitting. In that case, hyperparameter tuning won't help either.

The "may" part :

I have used hyperparameter tuning tools like HyperOpt that significantly increased my model's performance. Once you start working on neural networks, tuning your learning rate will have a massive impact as well.